# How to use exponents under special criteria

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and was trying to find a way to organize a specific function so I can take a list, apply special criteria to it, and then return another list.

I want to:

1) square a number if it is even
2) cube a number if it is odd
3) and then store those results in a list and return that list

Here is my code:

```
def square_function(x):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        x = [i ** (2)]
    else:
        y = [i ** (3)]
    func = [x, y]

    return func
```

I am very new to programming with python so any help you can give would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this could be what you are looking for:

```
from math import sqrt

def square_or_cube_function(x):
    result = []
    for i in x:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            result.append(sqrt(i))
        else:
            result.append(i ** 3)
    return result


print(square_or_cube_function([1, 4, 5, 8]))
print(square_or_cube_function([5, 7, 16, 32]))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[1, 2.0, 125, 2.8284271247461903]
[125, 343, 4.0, 5.656854249492381]
```

A shorter solution could be:

```
from math import sqrt

def square_or_cube_function(x):
    return [sqrt(i) if i % 2 == 0 else i **3 for i in x]

print(square_or_cube_function([1, 4, 5, 8]))
print(square_or_cube_function([5, 7, 16, 32]))
```

Same output.

Comment: `square_function` that also cubes?

Answer (score 0):

> take a list - apply special criteria to it - and then return another list.

You're looking for the `map()` function

```
def foo(x):
    return x**2 if x%2==0 else x**3

l = [1,2,3]
I = list(map(foo, l))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> [x ** 2 if x % 2 == 0 else x ** 3 for x in a]
[1, 4, 27, 16, 125]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another LC solution, but using a bit of cleverness:

```
[x ** (x % 2 + 2) for x in L]
```